# Calling variadic template function with no args failing

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... bargs, Args&&... aargs)
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo<int, double>(1, 2.0, 3, 4.0); //OK
    foo<char>('c', 'd'); // OK
    foo(); //FAIL
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
In function 'int main()':
15:9: error: no matching function for call to 'foo()'
15:9: note: candidate is:
6:6: note: template<class ... Args> void foo(Args&& ..., Args&& ...)
6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
15:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Is it possible to call such a function with no args? Can the function be changed to support zero or more args?

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly g++4.8.3 error too,maybe g++5.1 fix this problem.Thanks.

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly I can confirm that this works with clang 3.6. With clang 3.4 however you get an error and need to specialize `foo` for the case without args.

Comment: I guess this is g++ bug before g++5.1,because ISO c++ says A variadic function template can be called with any number of function arguments include zero.

Comment: See [CWG issues 1388 & 1399](http://wg21.link/cwg1388) and [Clang bug 21774](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21774). Someone should file a GCC bug - this shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify a version of the function without args:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... bargs, Args&&... aargs)
{
    std::cout << "Hello with args" << std::endl;
}

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Hello without args" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo<int, double>(1, 2.0, 3, 4.0); //OK
    foo<char>('c', 'd'); // OK
    foo(); // Also OK now
}
```