# Variadic template function with no template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following variadic template function in C++ 11:

```
#include <functional>

template<class... T>
void Subscribe(std::function<void(T...)> handler)
{
    // contents omitted
}
```

Which I can call fine like this:

```
Subscribe<int>([](int value)
{
});
```

But I can't call it with empty template arguments (it will not compile in Visual Studio 2015):

```
Subscribe<>([]()
{
});
```

I know there is a similar post:
[Calling variadic template function with no args failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995332/calling-variadic-template-function-with-no-args-failing), however, in that post no-one discusses the use of chevrons `<>` at the end of the function as the correct usage as with variadic template classes.

I don't want to duplicate the code inside the function body by declaring the no-arguments version separately. Is there a way to call the method with empty template arguments?

Comment: `Subscribe(std::function<void()>( [](){} ));`

Comment: The syntax `f<>(...)` was already used pre-C++11 to mean "`f` is a template; don't consider non-template overloads during overload resolution". It is for this reason, I suspect, that it couldn't be repurposed to mean "`f` is a variadic template with zero arguments". Before C++11, every template took at least one argument.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, `Subscribe(std::function<void()>( [](){} ));` works. Add it as an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks very much :-)

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, based on your idea, it looks like Subscribe((std::function<void()>)[](){}) also works to coax the compiler into resolving this call. Your technique will answer the similar post as well ;-)

Comment: When we keep editing the "c++" tag into your C++11 questions, that should serve as a hint that we want you to do that yourself from now on.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, will do, thanks :-)

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, your comment about the syntax `f<>(...)` was already used pre-C++11. I have been able to call a template method using f<>() if I create a method with this signature `template<class T = int>f(T i) { return i; };` then I can call it using f<>(1). This has made me confused.

Comment: `f<>(1)` would work even if you don't give `T` a default argument. See if [this demo](http://rextester.com/PISCX52438) clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way I know of to explicitly supply zero template arguments. `Subscribe<>` means something else, since pre-C++11 days: "`Subscribe` here is a template, don't consider non-templates during overload resolution."

One can use

```
Subscribe(std::function<void()>( [](){
    // ...
} ));
```

This relies on template parameter deduction to deduce empty parameter list, and clarifies the type of the function's argument to allow that deduction to succeed.